# Unified Audit record write to audit trail table failed with Unified audit disabled!

Tags: audit, oracle-19c

on a production database I keep on observing the following error:

2022-08-15T16:58:36.196692+02:00
Unified Audit record write to audit trail table failed due to ORA-4031. Writing the record to OS spillover file.

beside trying to flush the shared pool with no success.. Can someone explain me why I get this error despite UA not being enabled on this database? :)

PARAMETER               VALUE            CON_ID

---

Unified Auditing           FALSE                 0

Version is 19, no pdbs.

Could it be a bug? Should I open an SR to the Oracle Support?
Thank you.

Comment: This is most likely a memory leak of some kind, There should have been multiple trace files created, and may well require an SR with Oracle Support. It is doubtful you'll get much conclusive input from this forum on something that is likely *very* specific to your infrastructure.